# Domain limitations on generating function for Legendre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, binomial-theorem, legendre-polynomials, negative-binomial

The generating function for legendre polynomials is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt(1-2ut+u^2)}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty u^iP_i(t)$$ where $P_i$ is $i^{th}$ legendre polynomial however for binomial expansion of left hand side with exponent  -$\frac12$, we need to have $$|(u^2-2ut)|\le1$$. So how do we prove equality of two sides when this condition doesn't hold ? Or is it really a domain limitation ?

Comment: The ininite series on the right is a [Formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) in which $u^n\to 0$ is all that is required for convergence. This is also why dividing by $0$ on the left is not an issue.

Comment: So that's really a limitation on domain of u ?

Comment: You are misunderstanding "formal" power series. There is **no** domain of $u$. Think of $u$ as an infinitesimal non-zero number if that helps.

Comment: Ok, read on wikipedia and got some basic understanding of the difference. Thanks

Comment: @Somos: I've added a post which determines the region of convergence of the generating function when the Legendre polynomials are treated as analytical functions.

Comment: To be clear, it depends on the definition of Legendre polynomials. **One** definition is that it is the coefficient of $\,u^n\,$ in the formal power series $\,1/\sqrt{1-2ut+u^2}.\,$ As I mentioned in earlier comment, $\,u^n\to 0\,$ is all that is required for convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the sequence $\{P_n(t)\}$ of Legendre polynomials. We describe how to construct a generating function
\begin{align*}
G(t,u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(t)u^n
\end{align*}
and how to derive the region of convergence. We closely follow example 7.4 from  *[Asymptotics and Special Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FIXHNCG)* by F.J.W. Olver.

> We  recall  *[Rodrigues'  formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula)*
>   \begin{align*}
> P_n(t)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left\{\left(1-t^2\right)^n\right\}
> \end{align*}
>   and get  using  *[Cauchy's  integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)*  for the $n$-th derivative of an analytic function *[Schläfli's integral](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Schl%C3%A4fli_integral)*
>
> \begin{align*}
> P_n(t)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}\pi i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{(z^2-1)^n}{(z-t)^{n+1}}dz
> \end{align*}
>
> in which $\mathcal{C}$ is any simple closed contour that encircles $z=t$; here  $t$ may be real or complex.  For fixed  $\mathcal{C}$  and sufficiently  small $|u|$,  the series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z^2-1)^nu^n}{2^{n+1}\pi  i(z-t)^{n+1}}
> \end{align*}
>   converges uniformly   with  respect  to  $z\in\mathcal{C}$, by  the  *[M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)*.  By integration and summation we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2\pi   i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}\left\{1-\frac{(z^2-1)u}{2(z-t)}\right\}^{-1}\frac{dz}{z-t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  P_n(t)u^n=G(t,u).
> \end{align*}
>   It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> G(t,u)=-\frac{1}{\pi     i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{dz}{uz^2-2z+(2t-u)}=-\frac{1}{u\pi  i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{dz}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}
> \end{align*}
>   where
>   \begin{align*}
> z_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2tu+u^2}}{u},\qquad   z_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-2tu+u^2}}{u},
> \end{align*}

We   observe if $u\to 0$,  then   $z_1\to t$ and $|z_2|\to\infty$.  Hence  for sufficiently small  $|u|$, $\mathcal{C}$ contains $z_1$ but not $z_2$. The *[residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)* yields
\begin{align*}
G(t,u)=-\frac{2}{u}\frac{1}{z_1-z_2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tu+u^2}}
\end{align*}

We  conclude, the desired expansion is given by 
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tu+u^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(t)u^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

provided that $|u|$ is sufficiently small and the chosen branch of the square root tends to $1$ as $u\to 0$.

For $t\in[-1,1]$ the singularities of the left-hand side of (1) both lie on the circle $|u|=1$, hence in this case the radius of convergence of the series on the right-hand side is unity.